# r rolling custom function

Tags: r, zoo

I am trying to build a rolling take-profit / stop-loss detection function in R using zoo package.

```
    x <- as.data.frame(rnorm(10000, 0, 1))
    x$cumul <- cumsum(x[, 1])
    plot(x$cumul, type = 'l')
    y <- as.data.frame(x$cumul)

    level_break <- function(x, n, z){
    if (min(c(1:nrow(x))[x[, 1] > z]) <= n
        & (min(c(1:nrow(x))[x[, 1] > z]) < min(c(1:nrow(x))[x[, 1] < -z])
           | min(c(1:nrow(x))[x[, 1] < -z]) > n)){
        level <- 1

    }else if (min(c(1:nrow(x))[x[, 1] < -z]) <= n
           & (min(c(1:nrow(x))[x[, 1] < -z]) < min(c(1:nrow(x))[x[, 1] > z])
              | min(c(1:nrow(x))[x[, 1] > z]) > n)){
        level <- -1

    } else {
        level <- 0
    }
    return(level)
}

library(zoo)
yy <- rollapply(data = y$`x$cumul`, width = 1000, align = 'left', function(x) level_break(y, n = 1000, z = 1))
```

I am sure I am making something wrong. Could you please help me understand how to make it work. Or otherwise I would be happy to learn that there is a dedicated function in some package that does exactly what I am doing.

After all clarifications: An ultimate take-profit/stop-loss function:

```
#################### sl-tp

x <- as.data.frame(rnorm(10000, 0, 1))
x$cumul <- cumsum(x[, 1])
plot(x$cumul, type = 'l')
y <- as.data.frame(x$cumul)


level_break <- function(x, n, tp, sl) {
    if (min(c(1:length(x))[x > tp]) <= n
        & (min(c(1:length(x))[x > tp]) < min(c(1:length(x))[x < sl])
           | is.infinite(min(c(1:length(x))[x < sl])) == T)) {
        level <- 1

    }else if (min(c(1:length(x))[x < sl]) <= n
           & (min(c(1:length(x))[x < sl]) < min(c(1:length(x))[x > tp])
              | is.infinite(min(c(1:length(x))[x > tp])) == T)) {
        level <- -1

    } else {
        level <- 0
    }
    return(level)
}

library(zoo)

level <- 10
window <- 1000

start <- Sys.time()
yy <- rollapply(data = y$`x$cumul`
          , width = window
          , align = 'left'
          , function(x) level_break(x = x, n = window, tp = head(x + level, 1), sl = head(x - level, 1)))
Sys.time() - start

plot(yy, type = 'l')
```

Comment: "I am sure I am making something wrong". Why?

Comment: I do not get expected result. What I get is either a vector of "1" or "-1". This part seems controversial to me: rollapply(data = y$`x$cumul`, width = 1000, align = 'left', function(x) level_break(y, n = 1000, z = 1). I specify window to the zoo function, but I do not need that window at all. I just need a fast go through the lines. Then I specify window to my custom function again. However, if I call my function on one instance of a time series (without rolling), it works well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Orchestration logic is fine. I wrote a simplified version of rollapply to demonstrate it.

```
x = sample(1:1000,100,replace = T)
stop_loss = function(vec){
  if(vec[10]< 0.75*mean(vec)) return(TRUE)
  return(FALSE)
}

rollapply(x,width = 10,FUN = stop_loss)
```

The Output looks like:

```
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[16] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[31]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[46]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[61] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[76] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[91] FALSE
```

91 outputs on an input of 100 with a width of 10- perfect. That leaves your logic to be tested.

Looking at what you wrote, your input has a prob. You are passing the `dataframe y` into the `level_break` function. It's got to be `x`.

Now, you've written your function to take `x` as a `dataframe`, it goes in as a `vector`.

Here is what I changed your code to:

```
x <- as.data.frame(rnorm(10000, 0, 1))
x$cumul <- cumsum(x[, 1])
plot(x$cumul, type = 'l')
y <- as.data.frame(x$cumul)

level_break <- function(x, n, z){
  if (min(c(1:length(x))[x[1] > z]) <= n
      & (min(c(1:length(x))[x[1] > z]) < min(c(1:length(x))[x[1] < -z])
         | min(c(1:length(x))[x[1] < -z]) > n)){
    level <- 1

  }else if (min(c(1:length(x))[x[1] < -z]) <= n
            & (min(c(1:length(x))[x[1] < -z]) < min(c(1:length(x))[x[1] > z])
               | min(c(1:length(x))[x[1] > z]) > n)){
    level <- -1

  } else {
    level <- 0
  }
  return(level)
}

library(zoo)
yy <- rollapply(data = y$`x$cumul`, width = 1000, align = 'left', function(x) level_break(x, n = 1000, z = 1))
```

You'll need to check the min condition- It throws warnings. :)

Comment: I had a problem with infinity error. Now it throws warnings, but works.          `level_break <- function(x, n, z){
 if (min(c(1:nrow(x))[x[, 1] > z]) <= n
     & (min(c(1:nrow(x))[x[, 1] > z]) < min(c(1:nrow(x))[x[, 1] < -z])
        | is.infinite(min(c(1:nrow(x))[x[, 1] < -z])) == T)){
  level <- 1
  
 }else if (min(c(1:nrow(x))[x[, 1] < -z]) <= n
     & (min(c(1:nrow(x))[x[, 1] < -z]) < min(c(1:nrow(x))[x[, 1] > z])
        | is.infinite(min(c(1:nrow(x))[x[, 1] > z])) == T)){
  level <- -1
  
 } else {
  level <- 0
 }
 return(level)
}

level_break(y, n = 1000, z = 21)`

Answer (score 0):

jackStinger, thanks for acute eye. I indeed had mixed x-y and dataframe-vector. I updated the code and it seems to work just fine with rollapply:

```
x <- as.data.frame(rnorm(10000, 0, 1))
x$cumul <- cumsum(x[, 1])
plot(x$cumul, type = 'l')
y <- as.data.frame(x$cumul)


level_break <- function(x, n, z){
    if (min(c(1:length(x))[x > z]) <= n
        & (min(c(1:length(x))[x > z]) < min(c(1:length(x))[x < -z])
           | is.infinite(min(c(1:length(x))[x < -z])) == T)){
        level <- 1

    }else if (min(c(1:length(x))[x < -z]) <= n
           & (min(c(1:length(x))[x < -z]) < min(c(1:length(x))[x > z])
              | is.infinite(min(c(1:length(x))[x > z])) == T)){
        level <- -1

    } else {
        level <- 0
    }
    return(level)
}

level_break(y, n = 1000, z = 21)

library(zoo)

yy <- rollapply(data = y$`x$cumul`, width = 100, align = 'left', function(x) level_break(x, n = 100, z = 1))

plot(yy, type = 'l')
```

I am now passing x to my function, and inside that function it is treated as vector. It seems to work just fine. The last line of code - plots the expected results. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Hey! Happy to help! Would appreciate if you accept/upvote the answer if it was satisfactory. Also, you can edit your answers to add information instead of adding more answers. Cheers!

Comment: I am a newbee at SO and cannot vote. Thank you again. I deleted my redundant answer. Thanks :)